# How to support different languages with dynamic web data on Android?

Tags: java, android

I have an application that pulls information from a web server and displays it. I know that Android has some nice language features where you can put multiple strings.xml files inside the project for specific languages. Is there a way to convert the text from the server (which is in english) to whatever local the user has set on their device?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but that's usually done at the server-side with some kind of translation api. Even on Android, when an app needs content that hasn't already been pre-translated, it goes through a server for the translation.

For instance, you could use Google Translate's api (which is not free)
http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/overview.html

Or you could install some open source solution on your own server and use that remotely as well.